# Registering call logging service into RingCentral Embeddable results in undefined error

Tags: ring, ringcentral, central, ringcentral-embeddable

It appears all my current attempts to register a third party service (***My Single Page Application***) using **[RingCentral Embeddable](https://developers.ringcentral.com/embeddable-voice.html)** are proving difficult.  I'm using the `postMessage` API with type `rc-adapter-register-third-party-service` and the result remains **"undefined"**

```
document.querySelector("#rc-widget-adapter-frame").contentWindow.postMessage({
  type: 'rc-adapter-register-third-party-service',
  service: {
    name: 'TestService'
  }
}, '*');
```

Is there a resolution to this as I'm successful receiving inbound calls. When I use type **"rc-adapter-new-call"** for outbound calls it also works but third party integration is proving difficult and the link neither pops up on the softPhone.

**For more details see...**

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable/blob/master/docs/third-party-service-in-widget.md#register-your-service

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that we need to register service after widget loaded.
Here is a demo for it. Let me update the embeddable docs.

```
var registered = false;
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  const data = e.data;
  if (data && data.type === 'rc-login-status-notify' && registered === false) {
    registered = true;
    registerService();
  }
});
```